# Socket.io keeps trying to establish a connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, hapi.js

The client side is connecting to my server using the following...

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:52805');
```

and on the server I am making this connection using...

```
// Establish a connection with a WebSocket.
io.on("connection", socket => {

  console.log("Socket Connection");

  ...
```

Now if I check the console on the server side, in the console I get the following in regular intervals...

```
Socket Connection
Socket Connection
Socket Connection
Socket Connection
...
```

It keeps printing out *Socket Connection* even though I am not refreshing the client.

What is causing this and is this normal? If not, what can I do to prevent this? Is it normal for the client to keep polling the server?

**EDIT**

As an extra note, I am using *Socket.io* as a plugin with *Hapi.js*...

```
const sockets = require("./src/Playlist/index");


// Define the server.
const server = new Hapi.Server({ 
  port: process.env.PORT, 
  routes: { 
    cors: true 
  } 
});

// Socket.io plugin.
await server.register(sockets);

// Start the server.
await server.start();
```

Where `sockets` is just a reference to the `io.on("connection")` mentioned above.

Comment: (Rhetorical) question, if you were to write a program with only the code you've shown us, does that reproduce the symptom you're describing? If not, how do you expect us to know what's causing it? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not sure what more to add, I edited my question and have given everything to reproduce my code.

Comment: Please verify in the browser's dev-console that there is a stable connection at all.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Looks fine from the browser side and all the socket endpoints work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried initializing io with `server.listener` like this:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
const io = require('socket.io')(server.listener); // <--- THIS

...


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ...
});

...

server.start();
```

See: http://matt-harrison.com/using-hapi-js-with-socket-io/

Comment: No I have not, I will try this later and get back to you, I created a plugin instead based on another example I had seen online.

Comment: @Bolboa sure, try it and let me know!